# Controlling CacheItemPolicy properties from your config file - is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, caching, .net-4.0

With reference to the System.Runtime.Caching class in .NET 4.0 it seems possible to only set a limited number of things in the configuration file to wit:

- name
- polling interval
- the amount of memory that that cache is allowed to consume
- the percentage of memory that needs to be hit before the cache will be scavenged

A sample section is shown below:

```
 <system.runtime.caching>
    <memoryCache>
      <namedCaches>
        <add name="NameOfMyCache" pollingInterval="00:05:00" cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="0" physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="0"/>
      </namedCaches>
    </memoryCache>
  </system.runtime.caching>
```

However it appears none of the really useful items (IMHO!) are controllable from the config file. These are the options that are all in the CacheItemPolicy class such as AbsoluteExpiration, SlidingExpiration and Priority (I can understand how the Callback functions aren't exposed although I would expect to see some options as to what to do in the event that these were called)

The question is, is it possible to do this from a config file without going away and rolling your own custom sections?

Comment: Appears to be impossible, so have filed a Connect case here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/740522/cannot-control-cacheitempolicy-properties-from-config-file

Comment: You Connect case link is dead...  I would vote it up.

Comment: Indeed it is, and it appears the case doesn't exist anymore to vote it up. There must have been some cull of cases. Thanks for the heads up - appreciate it!